# Вычислить рост биржевого актива с начала торгового дня

Tags: excel

Имеется таблица, которая содержит котировки биржевого актива: дата, время, цена открытия, максимума, минимума и закрытия. Мне требуется на каждой последующей строке в столбцe growth вычислить, на сколько % цена выросла или упала по отношению к цене открытия этого дня, т.е. в формуле нужно как-то задать условие, чтобы цена открытия текущей строки сравнивалась с ценой открытия именно этого дня, а не прошлого (в архиве содержатся котировки примерно за 250 торговых дней). Сразу скажу, что не всегда имеется котировка по состоянию на 16:35 (а это и есть начало торгов), т.к. какие-то котировки в архиве могут отсутствовать из-за  некачественного архива:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ВПР(A2;$A$2:C2;3)
```

Функция найдет первую строку с датой текущей строки и вернет цену открытия. Дальше математика - смотря какой процент хотите получить. Например:

```
=F2/(F2-ВПР(A2;$A$2:C2;3))
```

Comment: честно говоря,  я уже сама решила эту проблему с помощью другой формулы. Но Ваш вариант меня заинтересовал, я попробовала, но не получается, т.к. с помощью ВПР возвращается не цена открытия первой строки, а последней... ПС А, я поняла, в чем проблема, в ВПР 4-м аргументом нужно дописать "ложь", тогда все верно!

Comment: Да, удалил случайно знак при правке...  `ВПР(A2;$A$2:C2;3;)`  Отсутствие аргумента после точки с запятой - это то же, что ЛОЖЬ или ноль